# Is it worth it to switch from home-grown remote command interface to using JMX

Tags: java

Without knowing too much about JMX, I've always assumed that it would be the best approach for building in remote management to our standalone Java server application. Our server application has some minimal remote control capability, using text commands sent via TCP/IP socket to it.

Using the home grown approach, it is fairly to add a new command. (Just create new command text, and the code to handle that in the message receiver).  On the other hand, we have hardly implemented any commands, even though there are many things we would like to be able to execute remotely.

I am trying to weigh the value of moving to incorporating JMX (learning it, and building the interfaces), versus just sticking with the home-grown approach. Does anyone have any experience or advice regarding changing an existing application to use JMX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question.

First of all answer is quite simple for me. Move to JMX for several reasons.

1. There are lots of stable proven JMX implementations  out there that you can simply use to bootstrap your application and you don't really have to maintain your code to be able to support different operations.
2. JMX is a very simple model where you have MBeanServer that hosts a bunch of services / MBeans that have properties and methods.
3. These services / MBean are exposed by MBeanServer in a protocol agnostic way.
4. If there is a need to connect to the MBeanServer using different protocol's its simply a matter of creating adapters.

To answer your other question, is it easy to migrate to JMX, the answer is it all depends. If fairly easy to migrate the implementations / services to MBean and expose only what you want to but the tricky part maybe how you connect to those services. So clients might have to rewrite some of the code.

Hope this help!

Good luck.